# Should you create an id column or is an unique name enough?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to create a table with accounts. It should contain a AccountName (primary key), Password and an Email.

But should i put an identification number as the primary key in it or is the AccountName enough?
What are the standards, benefits, drawbacks?

Answer (score 4):

If "AccountName" field is string I recomend you to create an AUTO INCREMENT ID, let's suppose that one day you have a lot of data in your table and you need to select 100,000 lines and order by all of them.

So if you have an INT AUTO_INCREMENT field to order it's nice.

It can helps you when you need to DELETE an item too, to indentity ID columns is faster and easy than VARCHAR fields.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents would be to always have an id number as the primary key since it is independent of the actual business rules. What I mean is the only reason you have the option is that the Account Name today is going to be unique. But what if down the line that changes? If you have a separate field as the primary key, you won't run into any hassle down the line if your requirements change.

Comment: I completely agree with this post. It's best practice to have your keys completely independent from the business logic. You are not forced to use an auto-increment primary key but what will happen if down the road you decide to have a table that is referencing this one. Like Account Roles for example and assign some roles by Account Name. And then guess what happens with the Account Roles table if you need to change an Account Name...

Answer (score 1):

You must have a `primary key`. If it's an ID, a Name or an Email, it's your decision. You must have in consideration the data model and requirements.

Answer (score 1):

An ID column is NOT required of course. But I have not seen any professional software that has no id column.

It is better to add an auto incremented primary key in order to have better performance on related tables. IDs are never changed once they are created. But account names, passwords or email addresses may be changed by the user.

Another point is that an integer occupies less memory than a string.

If you are using innoDB you will probably need indexes.  So it is good to define a primary key, and make it numeric. the primary key should be sequential and small.

A couple of years ago, one of my past mistake was indexing tables over e-mail addresses. I was thinking that an e-mail address can only belong to one person. An email address (eg: x@c.com) holds at least 7 bytes. What if I had to relate 10 tables? It makes 70 bytes for a row only. So any new row would require 63 more bytes for vain.

Comment: Yes, but i dont need an auto incremented primary key. And putting an ID as integer is just a waste. So far, i cant see the benefits of having an ID since you have the accountname to log on.

Comment: Why do you claim that an auto-incremented primary key will have "better performance on related tables"?  And why introduce performance into this?

Comment: Im not talking about performance... its just a waste of space to have 4 columns (ID, name, pass, email), if i could just have 3 columns (name, pass email). since you are not going to use the id to log on or anything

Comment: Yeah, you can't argue that it takes up less space, since the OP doesn't actually even need the field in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

You can assign primary to any column it's up to you but it is always better to assign auto increment Primary key to ID column.

In future, number of records increase then it will give problem if AccountName is same.